# I keep having this error when i run my page. can someone help me with this.(sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given )

Tags: php, sql-server

I keep having this error when I run my page. Can someone help me with this.`(sqlsrv_fetch_array()`

> expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM adminIPTable WHERE (adminIPaddress=? AND adminName !=?) ";

        // run the query
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);



            if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
            ?>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class=" col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Edit IP Address</legend>
                                <p id="error"></p>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">IP address</label>
                                    <div id="ipaddress" class="col-lg-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtip" value="<?=$row['adminIPaddress']; ?>" placeholder="Name" data-content="Please enter your IP" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtadmin" value="<?=$row['adminName'] ?>" disabled="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="checkUpdateProfile()">Update</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
```

Comment: var_dump($result) and check if there is any result .

Comment: a) yes, you need more error handling like [devpro suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34626808/4833) b) `WHERE (adminIPaddress=? AND adminName !=?) ` - there are two placeholders in that statement. You need [sqlsrv_prepare()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) to prepare the statement and bind those parameters.

Comment: yes agreed with you but where is OP? @VolkerK

Comment: here is no error now but the page is blank and it does retrieve anything. -@devpro

Comment: add an else-branch to devpro's answer `else { var_export( sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL) ); }`. If you're still using sqlsrv_query instead of sqlsrv_prepare with _that_ sql statement, the error is obvious. What are the values you want to use in place of the question marks?

Comment: i have this error nowarray ( 0 => array ( 0 => '07002', 'SQLSTATE' => '07002', 1 => 0, 'code' => 0, 2 => '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error', 'message' => '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error', ), ) im trying to retrieve the value adminIPAddress and adminName from database @VolkerK

Comment: "im trying to retrieve the value adminIPAddress and adminName from database" - For all records in that table? I.e. _without_ a [WHERE clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx)?

Comment: For all the records. If is not possible, is there any other suggestion in doing so? i wanted to retrieve and afterwards the user will be able to update. @VolkerK

Comment: Then remove the WHERE clause. `$sql = "SELECT * FROM adminIPTable"` or even better `$sql = "SELECT adminIPaddress,adminName FROM adminIPTable"` (* without a good reason is a bit frowned upon).

Answer (score 0):

You may have had error in the `$sql`

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

So the 
`sqlsrv_query()` might have returned `false`.

And then the `$result` went to `sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)` as it's first parameter.

hence the `"boolean given"` error.

Comment: please check error is `sqlsrv_fetch_array()`

expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given  , you have answered it considering `sqlsrv_query()`

Comment: `sqlsrv_query()` have returned `false` into `$result`
so the `$result` goes into `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` as `false` giving you that error.

Comment: How he will know if `sqlsrv_query()` has returned false , edit your answer and explain that and also add how he can avoid it .

Comment: apparently it was clear his query didn't execute as expected as @devpro pointed it out. sorry if i wasn't any clear.

Comment: Just edit your answer with all these things .so that your answer will be better and I can remove the downvote from your answer . I do not like putting a downvote that is why I am asking you to improve your answer .

Comment: Sure man. I did. I just recently started using stackoverflow. Perhaps I lack structured approach when answering. :D

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that, `$row` will not return you boolean, if you want to check status before display the result than you need to check like that:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($result === true){
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        // your stuff
    }
}
```

**PHP Manual Link:** [sqlsrv_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)